# Is there a standard way to start a “naked” browser window (Chrome, for instance) from the command-line via a script or from an app

Tags: browser, frontend, desktop

Is there a standard (possibly portable across OSes) way (or procedure or script) to start a “naked” browser window (Chrome, for instance) from the command-line via a script or from an app.

By naked, I mean : without the URL bar, tool bar etc. Basically: as a substitute for Electron (or Webview).

The aim is to make a front-end app (HTML, JS, CSS) look as much as possible as an Electron app or as a stand-alone desktop app.

Comment: What’s the reason you don’t want to use Electron?

Comment: Lots of reasons. One is : if the app contrains textareas, it will be able to benefit from the spellcheckers installed in the browser. Another is : No need to distribute Electron : The app is a lot smaller. Also the app is also more portable.

Comment: Of course, the same is true for webview.

Comment: All understood. Electron is a little bloated. NW.is is one that I read about that is more light weight than Electron. Ultralight is another one but you do have to code a little in C for the interface.

Comment: WebView is also a possible Electron-less solution: https://github.com/webview/webview

Answer (score 0):

This could do the trick:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1292666

However, the script would have to be adapted to make it portable across OSes.